# React Native: Preventing triggering of "focus" listener on navigation.goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am stuck with a situation where I have 3 screen i.e. `Screen1`, `Screen2` and `Screen3`.
I have `focusListener`on `Screen2`.

When I go from `Screen1` to `Screen2` `focusListener` triggers as desired. But when I go from `Screen2` to `Screen3` and goes back **(`navigation.goBack() which is default behaviour`)** to `Screen2`, `FocusListener` triggers again. I don't want `FocusListener` to be triggered when going back from `Screen3` to `Screen2`.

**Note:-** `Screen1` is in different navigator and `Screen2` and `Screen3` is in same navigator.

How can I achieve that? Please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

while going from screen 1 to screen 2 you need to pass a flag as true value, and from screen 3 to screen 2 passes same flag as false value, at screen 2 check your flag in focusListener , and if true then perform what action you want to perform.

for how to pass params visit
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: When I am going back, I am not calling ``this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2',{params})``. How can I pass params while going back. It is react-navigation default behaviour going back on back button press.

Comment: you need to add "hardwareBackPress" listener, which triggers on hardware back button press.
For how to do that visit https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/